# How to add search button to each column in react table for column filtering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-table

I am working in react table .  I need to add search button to each column for column filtering . As user enters a keyword to any of the column and  click on to the corresponding column  search button, it should perform an API call and display the value to the table . Sample UI and code are given below. Please let me know if idea is not clear.

[image]

**Code**

```
const columns = tableColumns.map(({ key, header }) => ({
        Header: (
            <Tooltip arrow title={header} placement="top">
                <strong className={classes.head}>{header}</strong>
            </Tooltip>
        ),
        id: key,
        accessor: key,
        headValue: header,
        Cell: row => {
            const { key: rowValue } = row;
            return (
                <div
                    style={{
                        textAlign: 'center'
                    }}
                >
                    {rowValue && rowValue}
                </div>
            );
        },
        width: 160
    }));
```

```
 <DraggableTable
                            showPagination={false}
                            fixedCol={fixedCol}
                            filterable
                            // onFilteredChange={(filter, row) => columnFilter(filter, row)}
                            handleColumnChange={onColumnChange}
                            rows={tableData}
                            columns={columns}
                            style={{
                                height:
                                    tableData && tableData.length === 0
                                        ? 200
                                        : tableData && tableData.length <= 8
                                        ? tableData.length * 50 + 60
                                        : 400,
                                width:
                                    columns && columns.length === 0
                                        ? '60vw'
                                        : columns && columns.length <= 3
                                        ? columns.length * 180
                                        : columns && columns.length <= 6
                                        ? columns.length * 200
                                        : columns && (columns.length > 6 && columns.length) <= 9
                                        ? columns.length * 170
                                        : // ? 'auto'
                                          '80vw'
                                // ? columns.length * 170
                            }}
                            getTrProps={(state, rowInfo) => {
                                return {
                                    onClick: () => enableCellClick && onCellClick(rowInfo.original)
                                };
                            }} 
                            resizable
                        />
```